# Help me to pick correct Honda Fit Aria Gear Box Oil

Tags: honda, oil, cvt-transmission, gear-oil

I have a honda fit aria, And in gearbox i can find (AFT DW-1) as the gear oil. 
but my gearbox is a CVT and the oil can says "DO NOT USE for CVT",  I am very confused wheather to use this gear oil or not, please help. 
[image]

Comment: So where does it say this **"And in gearbox i can find (AFT DW-1) as the gear oil"** as you may well be missing something... like a footnote that says only for the manual or somesuch...

Comment: Why not look for CVT transmission fluid? Such as [Valvoline](https://www.carid.com/valvoline/cvt-continuously-variable-transmission-fluid-mpn-804751.html)? (Just a suggestion, no affiliation.) I'm sure there's other brands out there you could use. If all else fails, go to your Honda dealership and buy from there ... they'll give you what you need ... for a price.

Comment: SolarMike, I quickly looked up the owner's manual for the Fit Aria (it was in Japanese...) and sure enough, it recommends ATF-Z1 fluid (now replaced by ATF DW-1). @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, I honestly wouldn't be so quick to recommend other fluids, because there must be some sort of reason that Honda recommends ATF... Maybe they just didn't have a CVT fluid back then? Or maybe it actually needs ATF? I would suggest **going to a dealership and asking them directly**, and then looking elsewhere to see if you can buy it for cheaper. In general it's not worth risking your transmission over some fluid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't use DW-1!**

ATF DW-1 *did* replace the old Z1 fluid - but **only** for conventional automatics.

For the CVT boxes Honda now produce their own CVT Fluid (Honda Part# 0826099905HE) which should be used instead - the first generation CVT boxes in particular are known to be a bit touchy about fluid and I've heard anecdotal reports of issues when using non-Honda fluids in them. As others have mentioned if you're having difficulty tracking it down a Honda dealer should be able to supply it.